# Multi-column list in awesome-cv

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, awesome-cv

I am using a [template found on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv-cover-letter/pfzzjspkthbk#.V-wE5ZMrJ-U) to build my resume but got stuck because I am new to LaTeX. I am trying to build up the coursework section, but things mess up.

[image]

Here is the code, I want to make the coursework section lined up well.

```
% Define an environment for cvitems(for cventry)
\newenvironment{cvitems}{%
                          \vspace{-4mm}
                          \begin{justify}
                          \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2ex, nosep, noitemsep]
                          \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
                          \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\bullet}
                        }%
                        {%
                        \end{itemize}
                        \end{justify}
                        \vspace{-2mm}
                        }%

% Define an environment for cvcoursework
\newenvironment{cvcourseworks}{%
                                 \begin{center}
                                %\setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
                                %\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
                                %\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{15.2cm}}
                              }%
                              {%
                                %\end{tabular*}
                                \end{center}
                              }%

% Define a line of cv information(course)
\newcommand*{\cvcourse}[2]{%
                             \vspace{1mm}
                             \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
                             \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
                             \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{12.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
                                 %\vspace{1mm}
                                 \multicolumn{2}{L{17cm}}{\descriptionstyle{#1}} 
                                \\
                             \end{tabular*}
                           }%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%in coursework.tex
\cvsection{Coursework}

\begin{cvcourseworks}
  \cvcourse{%
      \begin{cvitems}
          \item {Software Engineering}
          \item {Neural Networks}
          \item {Image Processing}
      \end{cvitems}
     }%
\end{cvcourseworks}
```

Comment: Please 1) add a link to the template you use; "template found on Overleaf" is not very specific and 2) make your code compilable and don't post just snippets.

Comment: this is the link to the template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv-cover-letter/pfzzjspkthbk#.V-wE5ZMrJ-U

Comment: There are thousands of lines in the whole template, I dont know if it is necessary to post them all. Based on my judgement, those codes are what related to the coursework section..

Comment: @KevinYao The point is that we have to compile the document ourselves to see the problem and also to test the solution. We appreciate it if you strip everything not relevant, as long as the rest still shows the problem. If the fragments you give are the essential stuff, then please add the few lines that it takes to make it compilable.

Comment: @gernot, thank you. Those codes are hardly compliable until I upload everything here. I just want some advice on how to add two bullets(which had the same settings in cvitems) in the same row and how to adjust the distance between each column( for here are the courses ) to align everything. I have changed something and I will edit the original post soon.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to define new environments of macros to hold or set your coursework. You should be able to just use something like this:

[image]

```
\cvsection{Coursework}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
  \begin{cvitems}
    \item Software Engineering
    \item Neural Networks
    \item Image Processing
  \end{cvitems}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
  \begin{cvitems}
    \item Articifial Intelligence
    \item Basketweaving
    \item Lightsaber Fighting
  \end{cvitems}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\linewidth}
  \begin{cvitems}
    \item Bear Tickling
    \item Crocheting
  \end{cvitems}
\end{minipage}
```

I've set each "column" inside a `minipage` that is anchored at the `[t]`op. You can adjust the width to spread out/condense the spacing.