# Bullet Point Alignment for \cvsection

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, itemize, cv

How do I align bullet points 3, 4, and 5 to be aligned on the left next to bullet points 1, 2, and 3 like the image below?

```
\cvsection{Education}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTENT
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{cventries}

%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cventry
    {Bachelor of Science } % Degree
    {University} % Institution
    {Location, USA} % Location
    {Aug 2022 - May 2026} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) bullet points
        \item {Bullet Point 1}
        \item {Bullet Point 2}
        \item {Bullet Point 3}
        \item {Bullet Point 4}
        \item {Bullet Point 5}
        \item {Bullet Point 6}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
```

[image: Example:]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and complete your LaTeX code accordingly. As it is, we can't copy-paste it to test it, and you seem to be using commands that come from an unspecified package...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for the bad code. I'm using a template called Awesome CV.

Comment: That doesn't help much, since that class doesn't seem to be included in CTAN: I have a full TeX Live 2022 installation, and this class is unknown. Please remember that debugging code that we can't see, using a class that we don't know is going to be difficult...

Comment: I found what I'm looking for. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331746/multi-column-list-in-awesome-cv.